# Selenium getText without descendants

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Is there a nice way to get text of current WebElement without text included by descendants?

Given a following structure in web page:

```
<div class="bottom">
  11:22:08<span class="hide-on-small-only"> UTC</span>
</div>
```

I want to extract `11:22:08`.

I am writing a test in Node.JS using selenium-webdriver 3.4.0. `webdriver.findElement(By.css('div.bottom')).getText()` will give me `11:22:08 UTC`. I could then remove the `UTC` substring: `webdriver.findElement(By.css('div.bottom span')).getText()`.

However I am looking for some more elegant solution. I.e. in jQuery I could do:

```
const getTime = () => {
  const timeElements = $('.nav-wrapper li div.bottom');
  return timeElements.contents().not(timeElements.children()).text(); // get rid of SPAN with timezone
};
```

One could answer that I should remove everything that follows space character, but this question is referring to a generic problem of extracting text without text included in descendants' tags.

Comment: @Marcin Can you consider showing us your work please? Thanks

Comment: @DebanjanB what do you mean by 'work'? I have described example scenario

Comment: Please consider showing us your `work`, `research`, `relevant HTML DOM` and the `error stacktrace` along with your `Test Environment details` for SO volunteers to analyse the real issue and help you. Thanks

Comment: I have edited question and added even more details. I think question contains all relevant information required to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get required output with `JavascriptExecutor` as below:

```
WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='bottom']"));
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
String time = (String) jse.executeScript("return arguments[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;", element);
```

Comment: Before I posted this question I had seen this one: http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/index_exports_WebElement.html It contains similar answer. Unfortunately it seems that JS `selenium-webdriver` does not provide such API: http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/index_exports_WebElement.html

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't noticed that you use `nodeJS`. Try `var time = driver.executeScript("return document.querySelector('div.bottom').childNodes[0].nodeValue;");`

Comment: This throws: `WebDriverError: unknown error: Runtime.evaluate threw exception: SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
       (Session info: chrome=58.0.3029.110)`. When I passte the "script" into browser console then it does not fail, but prints react comment. The time text is at childNodes[0]. This proves this solution is not very robust and reliable, because it includes invisible nodes. Better to do it in the way I described in question.